# Lodash unable to use chain with cherry pick import

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash (v4.17.11) features with cherry picking import in my project. When I do this:

```
import {chain} from 'lodash';
```

and

```
chain([1,2,3]).take(1)
```

it works fine, however, if I change the import to:

```
import chain from 'lodash/chain';
```

the output is:

```
TypeError: (0 , _chain2.default)(...).take is not a function
```

Can someone please explain what's the mistake here

Comment: What transpiler do you use and what is it configured to do?

Comment: Why is a transpiler relevant in this case?

Answer (score 1):

`import chain from lodash/chain` only works if there is a default export from the module.

If you want to import a particular named export - `import {chain} from lodash/chain` is the right way

See this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 0):

When you are using:

```
import {chain} from 'lodash/chain';
```

This treats the chain as named export not the default export from `lodash/chain`. But whenever you are point to a module lodash, in your case chain,  module would be a default export rather than a named export. That is why when you use `import chain from 'lodash/chain';`, it brings the default export from the module.

chain would be a named export is you are importing it from the root of lodash as following:

```
import {chain} from 'lodash';
```

You should probably have a look at [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) in javascript and have a better understanding of it.